# syntax error, unexpected end of file running php7

Tags: mysql, php-7.1

For the past hour, I can't seem to understand whats going wrong with my code, I am new to coding and I did some research and turn on short tags but I still seem to be getting an unexpected end of file error. any help would be amazing

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if($submit)
{//begin of if($submit).

// Set global variables to easier names
$title = $_POST['title'];
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];


//check if (title) field is empty then print error message.
if(!$title){ //this means If the title is really empty.
echo "Error: News title is a required field. Please fill it.";
exit(); //exit the script and dont do anything else.
}// end of if
//run the query which adds the data gathered from the form into the database
$result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO news (title, dtime, text1, text2)
VALUES ('$title',NOW(),'$text1','$text2')",$connect);
//print success message.
echo "<b>Thank you! News added Successfully!<br>You'll be redirected to Home Page after (4) Seconds";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=index.php>";
}//end of if($submit).


// If the form has not been submitted, display it!
else
{//begin of else

?>
<br>
<h3>::Add News</h3>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>">
Title: <input name="title" size="40" maxlength="255">
<br>
Text1: <textarea name="text1" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
Text2: <textarea name="text2" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add News">
</form>
<?
}//end of else

?>
```

Comment: If I change `<?` below the closing `form` tag to `<?php` it works for me. So it definitely still is a short-tag issue. After enabling them you need to restart your webserver. You can also check via `phpinfo()` if they are enabled. My personal suggestion though is not to use short-open-tags.

Comment: // If the form has not been submitted, display it!
`else` you need to change to `}else`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   <?php
    include("config.php");
    $error=0;
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    // Set global variables to easier names
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $text1 = $_POST['text1'];
    $text2 = $_POST['text2'];
    //check if (title) field is empty then print error message.
    if(empty($title))
     { //this means If the title is really empty.
    echo "Error: News title is a required field. Please fill it.";
    $error=1;
    }
    }
    ?>
<html><body>
    <br>
    <h3>::Add News</h3>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>">
    Title: <input name="title" size="40" maxlength="255">
    <br>
    Text1: <textarea name="text1" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
    <br>
    Text2: <textarea name="text2" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add News">
    </form>
</body></html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $error==0)
{
//run the query which adds the data gathered from the form into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO news (title, dtime, text1, text2)
    VALUES ('$title',NOW(),'$text1','$text2')"
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    if ($result==="TRUE")
    echo "<b>Thank you! News added Successfully!<br>You'll be redirected to Home Page after (4) Seconds";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=index.php>";
}
    ?>
```

Hope this answers your question. If it does, please rate my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it fixed my issue much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I made the same experience.
I had everywhere '<?php' as tag except one that was unfortunaly only '<?' and that was it for a round of sweat...
Changing '<?' to '<?php' fixed the problem - no need to restart the webserver!